# Android - Getting Context from a Method called within onReceive?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context, android-broadcastreceiver

How do you retrieve a `context` from within a Method that was called from `onReceive`?

**Here is an Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    ...
    if(...) {
        callMethodOne();
        callMethodTwo();
    } else if (...) {
        callMethodOne();
    }
    ...
}

private void callMethodOne() {
    // Cant use getApplicationContext
    SharedPreferences getPrefs =
      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}

private void callMethodTwo() {
    // Cant use getSystemService
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
      (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
```

As you can see, since the Methods are called multiple times/ways, moving all the code to be inside `onReceive` would end up being very repetitive and extremely inefficient.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
**Thank you.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it the `Context`:

```
private void callMethodOne(Context context) {
    // Can't use getApplicationContext
    SharedPreferences getPrefs =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}
```

Comment: **NOTE:** Clarifying for others - you cannot achieve this by _only_ doing the above within the the `method()`.. You must also include `context` when making the call from `onReceive` as well, such as `callMethodOne(context)`; and then you also have to include `context` either _in place of_ or directly _prior_ to each of the things you need it for in the Method, either such as above, or like `context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`.. Hope this helps clariy for others.